# Bridge edge loops with merge does not work in two directions

Tags: vertices, edges, tools

I have two tiles created using heightmaps in my project. The terrains don't completely line up, so I'm trying to merge the vertices together to make it seamless. I've found a few methods to do this, from merging the vertices by hand and using merge by distance, but the former takes too long and the latter doesn't merge all the points. The faster option I found is using bridge edge loops with the merge option checked on. It works well over multiple edges at once, but if the vertices swap top to bottom between the two tiles, the bridge does not work, throwing the "select at least two edge loops" error. Basically if all the vertices from Tile A are above the vertices for Tile B, the bridge works, but if half the vertices on Tile A are above Tile B and the other half are below Tile B, the bridge does not work. Does anybody know if there is a way to modify the bridge tool to bypass this restriction, or if there is an easier way to achieve the desired result?[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDZVw.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]